# a elements without href, or with an empty href, causes page reload when using Browser.application in Elm 0.19

Tags: url-routing, href, elm

Empty links, i.e. `a` elements without a `href` attribute or with `href ""` causes a page reload if used with `Browser.application` in Elm 0.19.

Here's a minimal, complete and verifiable example:

```
module Main exposing (main)

import Browser
import Browser.Navigation
import Html exposing (..)
import Url


type alias Model =
    ()


type Msg
    = UrlRequested Browser.UrlRequest
    | UrlChanged Url.Url


init () _ _ =
    ( (), Cmd.none )


update msg model =
    case msg of
        UrlRequested (Browser.Internal _) ->
            ( model, Cmd.none )

        UrlRequested (Browser.External url) ->
            ( model, Browser.Navigation.load url )

        UrlChanged _ ->
            ( model, Cmd.none )


view model =
    { title = ""
    , body = [ a [] [ text "click to reload" ] ]
    }


main =
    Browser.application
        { init = init
        , view = view
        , update = update
        , subscriptions = \_ -> Sub.none
        , onUrlRequest = UrlRequested
        , onUrlChange = UrlChanged
        }
```

This is non-standard behavior, as such links should not be considered hyperlinks by the user agent, and a lot of code depend on this behavior, among them [`elm-bulma`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/surprisetalk/elm-bulma/6.1.2/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is caused by Elm attaching `onclick` event listeners to all `a` elements to be able to intercept and handle routing internally. It parses the URL and categorizes it as either `Internal` or `External`, where an empty or omitted `href` is apparently considered `External`. Elm will then create a 'Msg' using the type constructor passed to `Browser.application` via `onUrlRequest`, run `update` passing this `Msg`, and this is where we can intercept and handle it appropriately.

The solution is to add another pattern to `update` which matches on empty external URL, where we simply do nothing instead of trying to `load` the URL as we normally would with other external URLs. In regards to the question's example the following updated `update` function should do the trick:

```
update msg model =
    case msg of
        UrlRequested (Browser.Internal _) ->
            ( model, Cmd.none )

        UrlRequested (Browser.External "") ->
            ( model, Cmd.none )

        UrlRequested (Browser.External url) ->
            ( model, Browser.Navigation.load url )

        UrlChanged _ ->
            ( model, Cmd.none )
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, that only concerns the view function, is to set the attribute `target` of the `a` element to `_self` in which case Elm will not navigate away.

There's an open issue about this problem in the [elm-browser project](https://github.com/elm/browser/issues/74).